# Openstack instance creation fails on attempt to attach a volume

Tags: instance, lvm, cinder

I am trying to get familiar with Openstack. I started out with devstack but was told by folks to use kolla-ansible as my base which I did. I am using the wallaby version all-in-one.

I successfully installed it and got public and private networks working something I struggled with in devstack. But unlike devstack, cinder was not automatically enabled in kolla-ansible.

I followed the steps for creating an LVM partition and used lvm as my cinder backend in kolla and then enabled cinder in the globals.yml file. I am now able to now volumes but I cannot create instances anymore. I get the following error when I attempt to create a new instance:

```
Error: Build of instance d37d1277-683e-41d5-8013-2dce63c3d655 aborted: Unable to update the attachment. (HTTP 500)
```

The instance is in an error state but the volume is created! I have looked around for a solution to this problem and have found nothing. Can anyone help me with what a possible fix for this is?

I was expecting that a volume would be created and attached to the new instance.